# I want to filter an array by first letter in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
function filter($fst, $arr){
$new_arr=array();

    for($i=0;$i<=(count($arr)-1);$i++){
        if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) == $fst){
            $new_arr[] = $fst;
        }
    }
    return $new_arr;
}



$list = Array("Apparel","Associations","Building/Grounds","Building/Materials",
              "Dispensing","Disposables","Distributors");

$new_list[]=filter("A", $list);

for($i=0;$i<=(count($new_list)-1);$i++){ 
    echo '<li><a href="?id='.$i.'">'.$new_list[$i].'</a></li>'; 
}

?>
```

I have created a function named filter() to filter the contents of an array that starts with a character like "a". It does not work at the moment.

Comment: I can see you like your `for` loops but they aren't serving you well in this code other than to make it more complex than it needs be. Try using `foreach ($arr as $arr_value) { (code) }`. That will cycle through each array entry and execute the code within the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I assume that you want to print the word that was OK and not the character you was checking with? `$new_arr[] = $fst;` should be `$new_arr[] = $arr[$i];`

Secondly you're adding the resulting array of the function into a new array instead of assigning the array to your variable. `$new_list[] =` should be `$new_list =`.

Here's an updated version of your code. I've marked where I've made changes..

```
function filter($fst, $arr){
$new_arr=array();

    for($i=0;$i<=(count($arr)-1);$i++){
        if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) == $fst){
            $new_arr[] = $arr[$i];         <----- Changed here
        }
    }
    return $new_arr;
}



$list = Array("Apparel","Associations","Building/Grounds","Building/Materials",
              "Dispensing","Disposables","Distributors");

$new_list=filter("A", $list);  <----- And changed here

for($i=0;$i<=(count($new_list)-1);$i++){ 
    echo '<li><a href="?id='.$i.'">'.$new_list[$i].'</a></li>'; 
}
```

Output:

```
<li><a href="?id=0">Apparel</a></li>
<li><a href="?id=1">Associations</a></li>
```

Comment: Np. You mark it as an accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to left of this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**first**
don't use

```
$new_list[] = filter("A", $list);
```

but simply

```
$new_list = filter("A", $list);
```

because your code will try to put an `$new_array` from `filter()` into next free index in array variable `$new_list`

**second**

```
$new_arr[] = $fst;
```

is wrong, because you're setting as new array value the `A` not matching word. use this instead:

```
$new_arr[] = $arr[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<=(count($arr)-1);$i++){
    if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) == $fst){
        //$new_arr[] = $fst; // <-- Bug is here
        $new_arr[] = $arr[$i]; // Try this
    }
}
```

And another bug:

```
//$new_list[]=filter("A", $list); // This
$new_list = filter("A", $list); // Should be this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $word) {
  // do something with $word
}
```

reads better than a C-style `for $i` loop